# When the android app is force stopped and reopened, will WorkManager executes overdue work or startover?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

Assume there is a scheduled work like this:

```
PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RefreshAuthWorker>(
    repeatInterval = 15L,
    repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES,
    flexTimeInterval = 5L,
    flexTimeIntervalUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES
)
```

Let's say, At 10th minute, I forcely killed/stopped the app.

Then reopen the app again after 10 mins.
by this time, the existing/killed work is overdue by 5 mins.
Now, What will the WorkManager do?

**1.WorkManager respects the missed overdue work and do it immediately and then schedule the next work.**

(or)

**2.WorkManager ignores the past overdue work and schedules the next work?**

This is a very important scenario to me because, let's say I have to refresh a token every 15 mins. But if WorkManager does like said in 1st point then, by the time I reopen the app, the token is already expired 5 mins ago and the next work is going to happen in 15 mins. So, it's a total of 20 mins with an expired token.

Can somebody who knows any idea what will the WorkManager do in such scenario, please help.

Comment: WorkManager will work in whether app is killed or keep in stack. app will create multiple instance of workmanger on everytime you open that activity. so just check the status of WM request by using tag. and cancel the previous process. and create new (depends on your use-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such things with a WorkManager.

1. Everything might happen if an application is forced stop. It is a problem of the user if he decides to do so. You should not care.
2. Are you sure you do not mean - clear from recent?
3. The priority of WM is saving resources like battery and network data. Timing is not a big concern. The idea is that you need some work to be executed for sure at some point. Like you want to upload a picture to a server.
4. What WorkManager does is - it creates a job in the JobScheduler. The job is executed when all the constraints are satisfied:

- You have implicit constraints related to battery saving. You have some amount of resources that you can use based on your Power Bucket level. Also, the device's state is important. You can't predict when these constraints will be satisfied.
- Also you have explicit constraints that you set. Like Connectivity, Battery level and in your case: "a period". But is a no period at all. When you have a "period" work on a higher level in the WorkManager - actually it means - many single jobs in the Job Scheduler. And each one of these jobs has the above implicit constraints and your explicit which is called - timing delay. So you see:

1. You start the work
2. WM schedules a job in JS with respective constraints
3. After 15min timing delay is satisfied
4. No one can tell what is the status of the implicit constraints. The device might be dozing, or you might have used all of your data usage for the last 24 hours or something like this.

---

5 At some point when all the constraints  are satisfied - the Work starts and when it is finished:
6. You have a new job with the same constraints as before. So in theory your "15min period work" might be executed in 24 hours and after that, it might execute the second time in 15 minutes.